# segment BCD to 7 decoder in verilog

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am writing a code for simulating a bcd to seven segment decoder. When i am doing so , i am getting red and blue lines in the waveform window(in Modelsim), which means that the input is not driven and the output is in undefined state. But when i running the code by forcing the values then it shows the correct results. From this i am able to figure out that the problem is in my testbench . I would rally appreciate if anybody can take a look at m code and point out what i am doing wrong.
**CODE**

```
//BCD to seven segment display
module seven_segment;
reg [3:0] BCD;
wire [6:0] display;
parameter stop_time = 200;


bcd_seven n(display,BCD);       //Instantiation of the bcd to seven segment      display code

initial #stop_time $finish;

initial
begin
BCD = 0;
#10 BCD = 1;
#10 BCD = 2;
#10 BCD = 3;
#10 BCD = 4;
#10 BCD = 5;
#10 BCD = 6;
#10 BCD = 7;
#10 BCD = 8;
#10 BCD = 9;
end
initial begin
$monitor("display = %d BCD = %b",display,BCD);
end
endmodule 

//Decsription of the BCD to seven segment display
module bcd_seven(D,BCD);
output  D; 
reg [6:0] D;
input [3:0] BCD;

parameter BLANK = 7'b0000000;
parameter ZERO = 7'b1111110;
parameter ONE = 7'b0110000;
parameter TWO = 7'b1101101;
parameter THREE = 7'b1111001;
parameter FOUR = 7'b0110011;
parameter FIVE = 7'b1011011;
parameter SIX = 7'b1011111;
parameter SEVEN = 7'b1110000;
parameter EIGHT = 7'b1111111;
parameter NINE = 7'b1111011;

//I have doubt especially in this section
always @(BCD)
case(BCD)
0: D = ZERO;
1: D = ONE;
2: D = TWO;
3: D = THREE;
4: D = FOUR;
5: D = FIVE;
6: D = SIX;
7: D = SEVEN;
8: D = EIGHT;
default: D = BLANK;
endcase
endmodule
```

Comment: I tried to run your code. Input is driven and the output is not undefined. It seems to be okay. What behavior do you expect?

Comment: u ran it in which simulator?

Comment: i except the testbench to work properly and hence when i run the code i should get the desired waveforms

Comment: running your code in icarus verilog should work.

Comment: Can u tell me what should i look for before knowing a particular code will work in a simulator, i mean can we get to know whether a particular style of writing the code will work with this simulator and not this one?

Comment: Works in ModelSim 10.1d, Riviera-PRO EDU 2014.10 on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/) icarus vrilog (0.9.6, 0.9.7, & 0.10.0) gave me issues, but easily resolved by changing `output  D; reg [6:0] D;` to `output reg [6:0] D;`

Comment: So u got the correct wave forms just by running the code and not forcing the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice one bug in your code. You are missing the case statement for BCD = 9. But that wouldn't explain the other issues you are seeing.